# Magento mini cart doesn't update

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I'm using magento 1.9.2.4, i don't know what's wrong with my site, but my mini cart doesn't update itself when i tried to add product. The mini cart's counts works well, but when i'm trying to view my mini cart, it says "You have no items in your shopping cart."

I already check my apache logs and also the magento logs, but there's no error log.
Thank you

Comment: Mini cart update is done using javascript (client side). Your php code that updates cart in the server doesnt work properly.

Comment: @AmitRay can you tell me which php code to update the mini cart?

Comment: I am not familiar with mini cart. But in general wherever cart is used when you add something in cart and the cart updtaes itself it is done through javascript, jquery etc. But when the ajax update is not done properly the cart doesnt update in server. therefore this error takes place. May be someone conversant with Magento can help you.

Comment: @AmitRay can you please check on my site? [link](http://sanvanina.com)

Comment: There is just some javascript error because if you try to right click and open its opening with all items added to cart. Check your javascript files again as getPreventDefault() is activated on cart link. Check the files that are connected to cart page. You will get some idea.

Comment: I think it's not about the theme (js), because i tried changing my theme and it still doesn't work